# Insert text into a textarea on a different page

Tags: javascript, html

Just wondering if anyone can help me. I'm building a refreshed version of a website and the old designer has put a feature on the website where when the user clicks on one of the icons it takes them to the contact page but also fills in the textarea on the contact form with the title of the link.

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to do this. This is not a duplicate question as I am asking how to do this across 2 pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use in javascript

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

then get text like

```
var textfromURL= getURLParameter('content');
```

and set that "textfromURL" in your text box

Comment: Without any serverside scripting, then URL querystring is the only way +1

Comment: Please update the answer, the OP has to provide the querystring in the link.

Comment: That is a conical link you can't determine parameters from that. @Mouser

Comment: @FrankTudor I mean for this to work the link has to be `href="?content=question"` in the a element. How else could the function `getURLParameter` parse content?

Comment: @mouser Oh, I see what you mean (you want it explicit).

Comment: so for a link id do <a href="" content="testing">Click to Insert</a>  ??

Comment: @AdamBoustead what that mean you have written above.

Comment: I dont get how to use it, where do i put the function, what do i put in the link etc?

Comment: I need to be able to attach a link to an image, this link takes the user to the contact page and fills out the textarea with a certain piece of text

Comment: First you put a link over your image like 
<a href="http://www.computer-repair-man.co.uk/?page_id=10&content=My desktop won't start" >
Start Up Issues
My computer wont start when I try to power on</a>
and on load of new page get the content parameter from the URL as above and set that in your text area.

Comment: is there anyway we can speak on a private message??